# Apache Whirr is not using my whirr.location-id parameter on EC2

Tags: apache, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase

I've been using Apache Whirr(0.8.0) to create Hadoop+HBase clusters on EC2 using the CDH ami, turns out that Whirr is not using my whirr.location-id parameter. I specifically pass it as an argument --location-id=us-west-2 when I create the cluster and I also added it to the whirr recipe as whirr.location-id=us-west-2 but when I fire up the clusters they always get created in the us-east-1 region. My guess is that the Whirr recipe for CDH is overriding the region and I wonder if there is any way to disable this or force an specific EC2 region?

Comment: can you provide ur file and commands that u ran?

Comment: I have a same issue so that I posted it at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WHIRR-678

Comment: Ravi:I ran the HBase script that comes with Whirr 0.8.0 and I was just overriding the cluster location. @Jongwook: Yeah I see that's still an open issue but thanks for filing the bug.